# Différences entre "regrets" et "remords"

Tags: sens, synonymes

Selon le **[Larousse en ligne](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/regret/67696)**:

> **Remords**:   - Vive douleur morale causée par la conscience d'avoir mal agi
>                    - Vif regret

et:

> **Regret**: - Peine causée par une perte, l'absence de quelqu'un, de quelque chose.
>               - Mécontentement, contrariété, déplaisir causés par quelque chose que l'on déplore, par la non-réalisation d'un désir, d'un souhait.
>              - Chagrin, repentir d'avoir fait ou de ne pas avoir fait

Il me semblait que le regret était toujours causé par un *vide* : une décision qui n'a pas été prise, quelqu'un qui est parti, un manque, alors que le remords résultait au contraire d'une action qui a été commise.

Je pourrais dire par exemple "J'ai des *remords* quand je pense à la manière dont j'ai indenté ma question, je *regrette* de ne pas avoir demandé à quelqu'un de le faire pour moi".

Cependant, la troisième proposition du Larousse dit "d'avoir fait ou de ne pas avoir fait". Et en effet, lorsqu'un enfant fait mal à quelqu'un, il ne dit pas "J'ai des remords" mais "Je regrette".

La différence est que dans le premier cas, c'est l'acte lui-même qui s'impose comme mauvais et qui vient peser, alors que dans le second cas, c'est l'acteur qui exprime un ressenti (je n'arrive pas à mettre de mots sur ce sentiment: l'acte peut ne pas être mauvais mais être regretté).

Quelle est donc la différence entre ces termes? Est-ce plus une question de nuance quant à l’honnêteté de l'acte?

Comment: ...la deuxième définition de "remords" dit bien "vif regret". Pas besoin de couper les cheveux en quatre.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi La raison pour laquelle il y a plusieurs définitions est parce qu'elles ne sont pas toutes vraies dans tous les cas. Si je n'utilise pas mon joker en demi-finale d'un jeu télévisé et que je perds, je peux ressentir un grand regret, un _vif regret_ ... Mais sûrement pas du remord.

Comment: Bien sûr que si, on peut avoir des remords dans cette situation. Par exemple sur le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/remords) on peut trouver la citation suivante "Argyropoulos, voyant l'enthousiasme du docteur, eut un remords, le seul qu'il pût éprouver du reste, le remords de n'avoir demandé que vingt-cinq mille francs". C'est quand même très semblable.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Dans votre exemple, Il éprouve bien des remords de quelque chose qu'il a fait: "avoir demandé seulement vingt-cinq mille francs". Mais je suis d'accord que si on le plaçait en négatif: "[...] le remords de ne pas avoir demandé plus", on arrive dans le cas d'une action non-commise. Dans les exemples sur le lien, on a cependant: "Avoir le remords de ne pas avoir rencontré qqn", ce qui colle tout de même beaucoup plus à la définition du regret, et "J'éprouvais une sorte de remords, de regret, ..." (de Proust) ou il n'y a pas de différence entre les deux.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Les citations servent à mettre en avant le sens des mots dans un contexte exemple, mais je recherche plutôt une nuance entre deux termes, ce qui est plus précis. C'est comme un exemple du verbe "penser" qui pourrait parfois mériter l'emploi du mot "croire" ou inversement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La différence principale selon moi n'est pas dans l'action / l'inaction, car on peut avoir des remords de n'avoir pas fait quelque chose (par exemple, avoir des remords de ne pas avoir dénoncé un proche dont le crime a fait beaucoup de victimes).

Une différence certaine est que le *remords* concerne les actions (ou inactions) de celui qui a le remords, alors qu'un regret peut tout à fait résulter d'une cause tierce. On peut par exemple regretter la mort d'un proche sans y être pour quelque chose, ou même regretter que le mauvais temps gâche une fête. On ne peut avoir de remords que de choses dont on est au moins en partie responsable.

La deuxième différence est l'aspect moral, de faute. Quand on a des remords, *on s'en veut* de quelque chose. Lorsqu'on a des regrets, c'est plus flou, c'est-à-dire que c'est parfois le cas et parfois non ; parfois un regret peut même être utilisé pour déflechir la faute (un docteur peut dire regretter la mort d'un patient sous sa garde, ce qui est une manière d'exprimer la compassion pour la famille sans impliquer sa responsabilité, alors que s'il a des remords c'est qu'il ou elle a quelque chose sur la conscience).

Enfin une dernière différence est l'intensité. On peut regretter d'être en retard à un rendez-vous mais à moins que cela ait des conséquences drastiques, on n'aura pas de remords à ce sujet. Le regret couvre une plage d'intensité plus large que le remords.

Comment: Entièrement d'accord.

Comment: Je suis bien d'accord avec cela! Particulièrement les deuxième et troisième paragraphes, je ressens cela en les lisant. Je n'arrivais à mettre des mots sur cette différence. Merci!

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que l'essentiel de la réponse est dans votre question : un remords est le regret d'un acte commis et qu'après réflexion, on aurait mieux fait de ne pas faire, qu'on a mal agi. Par contre pour une absence d'acte, on emploiera toujours regret, et pour un acte commis à regret mais où il n'y a pas de notion de "mal agi", on emploiera aussi toujours regret. Par exemple on dira "J'ai des remords de l'avoir insulté", mais jamais "J'ai le remords de vous annoncer la mort de votre père" => on dira toujours "j'ai le regret de vous annoncer la mort de votre père".

Quand un regret et mis en opposition avec un remords, alors le regret signifie spécifiquement l'inverse de remords, c'est à dire qu'on regrette de ne pas avoir fait. Ainsi on a une expression célèbre qui est "Mieux vaut avoir des remords que des regrets", c'est-à-dire que dans le doute il vaut mieux faire et assumer d'avoir fait plutôt que de se demander toute sa vie ce qui se serait passé si on avait fait. (principe très discutable, personnellement, je préfère regretter de ne pas avoir tué ma voisine qu'avoir un remords de l'avoir tuée ^^)

Mais quand on n'a pas une opposition entre un remords et un regret, alors regret peut s'employer à la place de remords : il sera juste moins précis. Et il s'emploiera d'autant plus facilement que regret a un verbe correspondant alors que remords non. Ainsi, on dira "J'éprouve un remords de l'avoir insulté", mais beaucoup plus simplement on dira "Je regrette de l'avoir insulté".

Comment: Merci de cette réponse! Personnellement, pour feu ma voisine, j'éprouve encore des remords.

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour,

La différence entre remords et regret tient seulement dans la notion de responsabilité/culpabilité. Il n'y a pas de distinction sur l'intensité ou alors l'action/inaction.

Remords : J'ai fait (ou je n'ai pas fait - intentionnellement) un acte/une décision et je me dis ensuite que j'aurais du agir autrement.

Regret : Un événement/situation. sur lequel je n'ai pas eu d'influence. Quelque chose que j'ai perdu, ou dont je n'ai pas bénéficié, sans que ce soit lié à ma décision.

Comment: On peut en effet avoir des remords de n'avoir pas agi ou mal agi.